# Using loadlib for DLLs in Lua

Tags: c++, dll, lua

I have a question that I can't seem to find an answer to.

When I load a DLL in lua using the loadlib, I can call functions in my DLL from the lua but is it possible the other way round, I'm thinking as a means for scripts to communicate, so would it be possible for my DLL to call a lua function in a script that has loaded the DLL?

This is within an existing game that is quite limited so a lot of the more sensible options are not at all possible.

Cheers for any help

Comment: I'ts very hard to tell where the problems start. I have used `LoadLibrary` very successfully but I can't tell why you can not.

Comment: I can use Loadlib fine to load in the DLL but I'm not sure how/if it's possible to call Lua functions from my C code as I know it's possible the call the DLL functions from the Lua but for my project I need the DLL to be able to call Lua functions. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not capable answering - but your question _is_ quite hard to answer with facts - as I see it. I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could visit this website to see whether it achieves your requirements.
URL:http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/lua/lua_c_calls_lua.htm.

Comment: That's interesting, although I have given it a read and I'm not sure that it would achieve what I want since my lua scripts are running in the lua interpreter in the game which has a library of extra functions added, It doesn't seem like I can call to an existing lua interpreter with that method?